# Counting primes

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, prime-numbers

Let $\pi(x)$ be the number of primes not greater than $x$.

[Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Prime-counting_function) says that $\pi(10^{23}) = 1,925,320,391,606,803,968,923$.

The question is how to calculate $\pi(x)$ for large $x$ in a reasonable time? What algorithms do exist for that?

Comment: What's wrong with the ones given on the page?

Comment: There is only one algorithm there. And I don't think it's possible to calculate $pi(10^{23})$ using it. Also there are no bounds on it's complexity.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The most efficient prime counting algorithms currently known are all essentially optimizations of the method developed by Meissel in 1870, e.g. see the discussion here http://primes.utm.edu/howmany.shtml

Answer (score 1):

You can use [inclusion exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to get a boost over the [Eratosthenes sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean, but Eratosthenes sieve is way too slow for numbers like 10^23. Could you provide an asymptotic complexity of your approach?

Answer (score 1):

The [Sieve of Atkin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin) is one of the fastest algorithm used to calculate $pi(x)$. The Wikipedia page says that its complexity is O(N/ log log N).

(edit)

I found a [distributed computation project](http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/Primes/Pix/pixproject.html) which was able to calculate $pi(4\times 10^{22})$, maybe it could be useful.

Comment: There is no way that $\pi(10^{23})$ could be calculated using the sieve of atkin (in any reasonable amount of time)

Comment: Right. This pages could be useful: 

http://www.ams.org/mcom/1996-65-213/S0025-5718-96-00674-6/S0025-5718-96-00674-6.pdf

http://www.ieeta.pt/~tos/primes.html

Comment: This is one of the papers linked to on Bill's page; they were able to use it calculate $\pi(10^{18})$, but more advanced refinements were needed to calculate higher than that